# Change the attribute "for" in "Html.LabelFor"

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

I need to change the `id` property of my model, so do I assign a new `id` in the method `TextBoxFor` from `HTML helper`. But this obviously did not change the `id` in the `for` attribute when using the method `LabelFor` from `HTML helper`.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MyProperty, new { id = "CustomId" })
```

How I can change the `for` attribute when using the method `LabelFor` from `HTML helper`?. because this method does not allow changing attributes.

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.MyProperty)
```

Perhaps there is an attribute to change the `id` in the model property.

thanks

**Edit for comment**

I use `LabelFor` because I need to take the name from the `DataAnnotation` `Description`:

```
[Display(Name = "Name of my property")]
public string MyProperty { get; set; }
```

Comment: No reason to use `Html.LabelFor` if you don't want to tie the label to the matching field from the model, try with `Html.Label` instead.

Comment: why do you need to set the id in the first place?

Comment: @DanielA.White Acessibility standards Html (+SEO)

Comment: it doesnt help with that at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to create your own extension for that, I've made one that takes html attributes, you might be able to use that to solve your problem:

```
public static MvcHtmlString LabelFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, Object htmlAttributes) {
    ModelMetadata metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression<TModel, TValue>(expression, html.ViewData);
    String fieldname = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);

    fieldname = metadata.DisplayName ?? metadata.PropertyName ?? fieldname.Split(new Char[] { '.' }).Last<String>();
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(fieldname)) {
        return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
    }
    TagBuilder tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("label");
    tagBuilder.Attributes.Add("for", TagBuilder.CreateSanitizedId(html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(fieldname)));
    tagBuilder.SetInnerText(fieldname);
    RouteValueDictionary attr = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);
    tagBuilder.MergeAttributes<String, Object>(attr);
    return tagBuilder.ToMvcHtmlString();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

ViewModel:

```
public IEnumerable<SportingLisbon> SportingLisbonList { get; set; }
```

View:

```
 @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SportingLisbonList, new { @for = "IdSportingLisbon" })
```

Browser:
<label **for="IdSportingLisbon"**>Sporting Lisbon</label>

Description:
Set a different **for** attribute on LabelFor.

---

Without *new { **@for = "IdSportingLisbon"** }*

Browser:
<label **for="SportingLisbonList"**>Sporting Lisbon</label>

---

web.config:
`<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />`

```
<assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
```

Comment: Please format correctly as code sample. And a little descriptive text is always nice ;o)